# In the last layer, the nozzle should be at 210 °C of temperature configured in the Prusa Slicer profile

Tags: prusaslicer

I would like to create a profile, in the Prusa Slicer software, that could be preset so that in the last layer the nozzle is at 210 °C of temperature so that the printer ensures that the inner and outer walls are well together and do not become loose in the layer higher. I have very thin 0.7 mm walls and I usually have problems with the walls opening every now and then...

Comment: "The beak" - It would be beneficial if you could explain (even better if there was a picture) of what you are referring to.

Comment: I think beak is nozzle? Correct? Furthermore, if walls not stick together you probably have different issues. You could lower the extrusion width to 0.35 mm on a 0.4 mm nozzle. Also look into [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6068/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the printer settings custom G-code you could add a custom G-code there

```
{if layer_num == (total_layer_count-1) } M104 S210 {endif}
```

But that does not sound right why not start with 210 °C in the first place? It is perfectly OK to print PLA at 210 °C.